# combine array of object if atleast one property is common

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, array-map

```js
//this one is actual array

 const data = [
        {
          name: 'shanu',
          label: 'ak',
          value: 1,
        },
        {
          name: 'shanu',
          label: 'pk',
          value: 2,
        },
        {
          name: 'bhanu',
          label: 'tk',
          value: 3,
        },
      ];
>

//and this  is the array that I want
let outPut =
[
{
name:'shanu',
label:['ak','pk'],
value:[1,2]
},
{
name:'bhanu',
label:['tk'],
value:[3]
}
]
```

Comment: What you have done so far?

Comment: hi Nitheesh
 I'm confused where to start to get output like that, because of that only I didn't mentation what  I did

Comment: If `name` was not common, but `label` was common - what should the `output` be? For example `name` is shanu, manu, bhanu. But, label is ak, ak, tk. Should output be combined like `name: ['shanu', 'manu'], label: 'ak', value: [1, 2]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Array.prototype.reduce()` like this:

```js
const data = [
  {
    name: 'shanu',
    label: 'ak',
    value: 1,
  },
  {
    name: 'shanu',
    label: 'pk',
    value: 2,
  },
  {
    name: 'bhanu',
    label: 'tk',
    value: 3,
  },
];

const output = data.reduce((prev, curr) => {
  const tmp = prev.find((e) => e.name === curr.name)
  if (tmp) {
    tmp.label.push(curr.label)
    tmp.value.push(curr.value)
  } else {
    prev.push({
      name: curr.name,
      label: [curr.label],
      value: [curr.value],
    })
  }
  return prev
}, [])

console.log(output)
```

Comment: thanks  Kien Nguyen it's really helpful

Comment: It would be even a better answer if you explain the code..